# what does Total mean in jmeter listener Summary Report table for transaction controller

Tags: jmeter

I have test plan with 1 transaction controller, inside controller i have 2 http sampler. 
When generate Summary Report table, i have output

[image]

what does Total mean in jmeter listener Summary Report table for transaction controller?
why i have 1500 in the total, in transaction controller i have 500 ( combine from 2 sampler).
and my understanding is total should be 1000 (from 2 sampler) or 500 (from 1 transaction controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total row just sums up all the rows reported. (http samplers and transaction controllers if any).

Following are how `Total` row values are calculated:

```
#Total Samples = all rows Samples addition (= 500 + 500 + 500)
#Total min = min of all rows min, min(153, 239, 418) = 153
#Total max = max of all rows max, max(3788, 2218, 4008) = 4088
#Total throughput = all rows throughput addition (= 4.2 + 4.2 + 4.2)
```

---

`Transaction` is defined as collection of multiple HTTP requests (samplers). You use [transaction controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to know the collective response times for a bunch of requests related to one transaction.

**Real-time example:** Loading Home Page of any web application, triggers multiple HTTP requests to load resources like images, .js, .css. In JMeter, each HTTP request is represented as HTTP Sampler. you get those response times by default at the sampler level. but you want to know `overall response time to load the page`. so, you group all those requests under one `transaction controller`, which calculates the overall metrics based on all its child samplers/requests to give the overall response time to load the page, i.e., at the transaction level.

Transaction Controller (TC) row values defined as follows:

```
#TC Samples = how many times the transaction is performed (= number of times any of its child sampler, http request, is sent i.e., 500)
#TC min = sum of min response times of all child samplers (153+239) // min resposne time to perform the transaction
#TC max = sum of max response times of all child samplers (3788+2218) // max resposne time to perform the transaction
#TC throughput = each child sampler throughput (= 4.2)
```

Comment: Thx @Naveen, it's mean when using transaction controller, i can ignore the output of the Total row? and for collective response data i should use data from Transaction Controller row? throughput bit confusing, from your row calculation max and mix are from addition but transaction controller from one of the sampler?

Comment: yes, that's correct. you should know what value refers to what. so that tells you whether to ignore it or consider it in analysis.